# How does one do the reverse of fill-region / fill-paragraph in emacs?

Tags: fill-paragraph

The commands `fill-region` (and `fill-paragraph`) breaks lines in a region (and paragraph) to a predefined width. How does one achieve the opposite effect?

Given a buffer, say markdown or org, where paragraphs are separated by two newlines, how does one *unfill* (remove non-paragraph related line breaks) regions and paragraphs?

There are some hacks to do this, however wanted to know what is the canonical way:

1. Set the variable `fill-column` to a high value and run `fill-paragraph`.
2. Use a custom macro.

Answer (score 8):

Try `M-x unfill-region` and `M-x unfill-paragraph`.  Their documentation says that they are the respective inverses of those two commands.

Edit:

Forgot that this is not built in.  You want package `unfill` from MELPA, or at https://github.com/purcell/unfill

Comment: These functions aren't part of Emacs. Do you know where you got them?

Comment: You're right! Sorry about that. Been using them so long I forgot they were extras. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

spacemacs has a nice design regarding this in better defaults layer. from it's manual:

> Fill or unfill paragraph: Pressing M-q for the first time fills current paragraph and pressing M-q for the second time unfills it.

It achieves this by consulting the `last-command` variable.

Personly I just use evil's join(J) command, or Emacs's delete-indentation(M-^).

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this from the Emacs wiki:

```lisp
(defun my-unfill-paragraph (&optional region)
  "Make multi-line paragraph into a single line of text.

REGION unfills the region.  See URL
`https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph'"
  (interactive (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only) '(t)))
  (let ((fill-column (point-max))
        ;; This would override `fill-column' if it's an integer.
        (emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column t))
    (fill-paragraph nil region)))
```

It works by setting the upper limit on the `fill-column` variable to the maximum point in the buffer.  The `fill-column` variable controls the column beyond which automatic line-wrapping should happen. It also sets `emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column` to `t` which means that the fill column for lisp docstrings should use the same fill value as that given by `fill-column`.  In essence, this removes line-wrapping.  Finally, it calls the fill command for the region or current paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a quick built-in solution that works in all cases. For a single paragraph, you can:

1. Mark the paragraph (`mark-paragraph`, `M-h`).
2. Remove the beginning and ending line break from the region (`right C-x C-x left`).
3. Replace line breaks by spaces (`C-M-% C-q C-j RET SPC RET !`).

This is unwieldy enough that setting `fill-column` to a very high value and running `fill-region` tends to be more convenient. Doing it for multiple paragraphs is even more unwieldy because there isn't a regular expression that matches line breaks that aren't paragraph breaks.

If you don't want to modify `fill-column`, you can:

1. Create an indirect buffer: `C-x 4 c`
2. Set `fill-column` in the indirect buffer: `M-x set-variable RET fill-column RET 99999999 RET`
3. (Select what you want and) `M-q`
4. Close the indirect buffer (C-x k RET C-x 0).